# Showing a certain operator is trace class.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry

Let $E \to M$ be a vector bundle over a closed manifold $M$.  Suppose $T$ is an endomorphism from $L^2$ sections of $E$ to itself.  How does one prove that $T$ is trace class if the image of $T$ is contained in smooth sections of $E$?

Thanks.

EDIT

---

Yea I guess I should provide context since there may be assumptions I'm not stating.  This is from Singer's "[Recent applications of index theory for elliptic operators](http://books.google.com/books?id=dHyvUjE-OpoC&lpg=PR3&ots=fThmxDnZZa&dq=%22recent%20applications%20of%20index%20theory%20for%20elliptic%20operators%22&pg=PA29#v=onepage&q&f=false)". Specifically the part in the middle of the second paragraph of the proof, beginning with

> To show $P_j {_j S_f} P_j$ is trace class, it suffices to show that $_j S_f P_j$ maps $L_2(E_j)$ continuously into $C^\infty(E_j)$...

Comment: Where did you encounter this statement?

Comment: @NateEldredge I've updated my question with context.

Comment: You can make nice links by using the code `[nice link description](http://nicelink.direction.here/nicelink)`

Comment: @Pragabhava thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a proof, which is available [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=5oJG0ukOVswC&lpg=PA184&ots=7nR1FK0gBj&dq=sobolev%20%22trace%20class%22%20smooth%20functions&pg=PA184#v=onepage&q&f=false).